# Discrete math: determine whether $f(x) = x\log(x)$ is an element of $O(x^2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, solution-verification

I'd really appreciate if someone could let me know if this is a valid approach to proving that $f\left(x\right) = x\log \left(x\right)$ is in fact not of complexity $O\left(x^2\right)$:

**Proof by contradiction**

I'll assume that $f\left(x\right) = x\log \left(x\right)$ is of complexity $O\left(x^2\right)$, which implies that for some witnesses $c$ and $k$, for all $x \geq k$, we have that $f\left(x\right) \leq c * x^2$. Let us choose $k = 1$ such that $x \geq 1$:

1. $x \log \left(x\right) \leq c*x^2$
2. $\frac{\log \left(x\right)}{x} \leq c$ (note that this is because $x \ne 0$)
3. An expression involving variables cannot always be less than a chosen constant. Therefore, this function does not satisfy the requirements for complexity of $O\left(x^2\right)$.

Comment: $c=1$ seems to work

Comment: $\log x < x$ for large enough x

Comment: Hmm, and I actually just checked the graph of $xlog(x)$ and it tapers off to zero as x goes to infinity (by L'Hospitals). Ouch. Okay, how could I mathematically prove that it is of x^2 complexity?

Comment: or you mean $\theta(x^2)$ ?

Comment: Edit: I'm stupid, lol. Could I take the limit as x approaches infinity, find the horizontal asymptote of 0, and argue that for any c > 0, this will hold true?

Comment: @Mudream The problem deals with Big-O notation

Comment: How do you get #3? $log(x)\over x$ has a maximum of $1\over e$, so it's always less that $c > \frac1e$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem:**
> Suppose that $f_1(x)$ is $O(g_1(x))$ and $f_2(x)$ is $O(g_2(x))$. Then $(f_1 f_2)(x)$ is $O(g_1(x)g_2(x))$.

Let $f_1(x) = x$ and $f_2(x) = logx$ be functions.

First, a big-$O$ estimate for $f_1(x)$ will be found. $x \leq x$ holds for all $x$. This shows that $f_1(x)\in O(g_1(x))$ where $g_1(x) = x$.

Now we turn to $f_2(x)$. $logx \leq x$ holds for all $x>0$. Hence, $f_2(x) \in 
O(g_2(x))$ where $g_2(x)=x$

According to theorem $(f_1 f_2)(x) \in O(g_1(x)g_2(x)) \implies xlogx \in O(x^2)$